# Accessing admin Account in Joomla

Tags: joomla

Is there any way I can access the admin account of a website built in Joomla,if I dont have the password for the admin account.I do have all the privileges on the server. Please let me know your suggestions and opinions.

Comment: Is this helpul: [How do you recover your admin password?](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_your_admin_password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is stored in the MySQL database jos_users  table password  field. (change this for your table prefix if different)

Use a MySQL utility such as phpMyAdmin or MySQL Query Browser to edit this field.
Open the table, find your admin username, and then select that row for editing.
The password must be hashed (MD5), you cannot simply enter text into this field.

Set the password to a known value eg:
- admin = 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3

Source: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=10985

Answer (score 0):

The admin password you can find it in {DB_PREFIX}_users, the password is hashed (MD5) ...

Well it's a little more complicated than that, the hash is formed like {hashedpassword}:{hashedsalt}, the hashedpassword is formed by md5(password.hashedsalt) ...

so you can make a little script to echo a new password ...

```
<?php
   $psw = 'hashedpassword:hashedsalt';    // you copy the entry from the db here
   $newpassword = 'newpassword';   // your new password
   list($hashedpassword, $hashedsalt) = explode(":", $psw);
   $newpsw = md5($newpassword.$hashedsalt);
   $output = $newpsw.":".$hashedsalt;
   echo $output; // this is what you put in the db
?>
```